# CSS Hover Effect changing text style elsewhere

Tags: html, css

**BACKGROUND**

I would like to be able to hover over a link and a set of text fade out on this action

**HTML**

```
<nav class="PageNav">
<ul>
    <li id="HomeLink"><a href="http://www.example.com">Home</a></li>
    <li id="OverviewLink"><a href="http://www.example.com/overview">Overview</a></li>
    <li id="ServicesLink">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/services">Mega Services</a>

        <ul class="PageSubNav">
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/services/subpage">Subpage 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/services/subpage">Subpage 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/services/subpage">Subpage 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/services/subpage">Subpage 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/services/subpage">Subpage 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.example.com/services/subpage">Subpage 6</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li id="GalleryLink"><a href="http://www.example.com/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    <li id="VideoLink"><a href="http://www.example.com/video">Video</a></li>
    <li id="ContactLink"><a href="http://www.example.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

  <article class="ContentText">
       <p>text</p>
       <p>dummy text</p>
       <p>Dummy text, dummy text, dummy text, dummy text, <strong>3 Paragraphs, Roughly 209 Words</strong></p>
  </article>
```

**CSS**

```
#ServicesLink:hover .ContentText p {
     color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

I'm having trouble in thinking this one through, here's what I have but to no avail.

The idea being that when one hovers over the "mega services" tab the text contained in the article section fades.

Comment: Tried the CSS style `opacity`?

Comment: sorry I should've mentioned it's not the css style itself I think its the "#ServicesLink:hover .ContentText p {}" part that is at fault ... When I use the style `.ContentText p { color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);}` it works as expected. Now I need that to take effect only when the tab is hovered over

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this with css. You'll need some javascript.

Comment: As the answer currently points out, you can only select a CHILD element from this.

Comment: okay javascripting isn't a problem. Just checking I couldn't use CSS

Answer (score 1):

What your CSS is doing is targeting `.ContentText p` **inside** `#ServicesLink` -- which doesn't exist.

Your `.ContentText` is out of the CSS scope. There is no way in vanilla CSS to target selectors outside of it's parent.

JavaScript is your only valuable solution to scope elements on your page.

What is the aim or purpose of this, so we could maybe give you a better answer?

**UPDATE:** Updated answer.

In JS, you can do the following:

```
var hoverEl = $('#ServicesLink');
var targetEl = $('.ContentText p');

hoverEl.on('mouseenter', function() { 
  targetEl.css({'color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'});
});

hoverEl.on('mouseleave', function() { 
  targetEl.css({'color': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'});
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/JMDUK/pen/wGbCf)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by declaring `opacity:0` for mega services (I suppose id ServicesLink). Or, if you want it to be smoother you can use jQuery:

```
$("#id_where_you_hover").hover(function(event){
  $("#id_that_you_want_to_fade_out").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).html("here you put something to replace if you want").fadeIn(2000);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with CSS currently.

You will have to use JavaScript.